# iAd in multiple view controllers example

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, uiviewcontroller, iad

I have noticed the example tabbed bar application in the iAd suite only has one view controller and the actual tab bar proccess is coded. I have a tab bar application already, with three tabs, each with their own view controller. Where can I find an example of a shared banner view that acctually has several view controllers? I dont want a video tutorial! If there are no examples, then can you give me instructions or a link to a website (no video!) which tells me how to implement a shared banner view into multiple view controllers?

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you are developing for iphone and portrait mode only then you can place ad on windows and you can access that adview from anywhere by using appDelegate.